# Manage Windows Server Core 2012 from Server Manager on a Windows 7 machine

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, windows

I wanted to find out if it is possible to manage Windows Server Core 2012 running Hyper-V from a Windows 7 machine.

I seem to be able to connect to Hyper-V using the Hyper-V manager, but I can't seem to connect to the machine from Server Manager.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need the Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows Server 2012, which is not available for Windows 7 (at least not yet).

The only option right now is to use Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012 on your workstation. The RSAT for Windows 8 is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972

Answer (score 4):

Not true.

You can use Hyper-V tools in Windows 7 (Hyper-V Manager 6.1) to connect & manage a Windows 2012 Hypervisor. Just install the RSAT package. Yup may have to run a Windows script from an elevated prompt to correct security (Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value  -Concatenate), where RemoteServerName if your Hyper-V server.

Comment: You can, but as far as I can see new machines use the .vhd format rather than the .vhdx format, and I don't seem to be able to use .vhdx disk image files. Can anybody else verify?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what exactly you mean by "manage."

[You can connect to the `CLI` remotely easily enough](https://serverfault.com/questions/429426/how-can-i-connect-to-a-windows-server-using-a-command-line-interface-cli), as mentioned by some brilliant guy in the linked thread, and you can manage it all from there.  Hopefully you're comfortable on the Windows `CLI`.

As mentioned in pauska's answer, the Remote Server Administration Tools for GUI access are not available for Windows 7, at least not yet, so managing it through a GUI isn't an option unless you install Windows 8 or a "Full" Server 2012 edition on a workstation to manage your 2012 boxes with.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the RSAT tools itself are only available for Windows 8, you can still manage quite a few things from Windows 7.

Via the standard MMC Computer Management you can use:

- Task Scheduler (throws some anoying alerts, but you can still manage tasks)
- Event Viewer
- Shared Folders
- Local Users and Groups
- Performance
- Services

You can also use IIS Manager except for a few things like SSL certificates

So it depends what exactly you want to administrate.

Answer (score 0):

The officially supported answer to your question is Microsoft's System Center Virtual Machine Manager.  Support for Server 2012 in SCVMM is still in Beta.  When it is released, it will be the tool though which you can manage multiple different hypervisors, including multiple versions of Hyper-V.

The built-in (or RSAT-supplied) Hyper-V manager only manages same-level versions of Hyper-V.  I.e. Windows 7 only manages Server 2008 R2 and Windows 8 only manages Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage Server 2012 with RSAT 6.1 for Windows 7. Download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887 After installing the update it will show up in *Programs and Features* under *Turn Windows features on or off*.

HOWEVER: You cannot manage Server 2012 **R2** with RSAT 6.1. For that you need RSAT 6.2 which is only available on Windows 8 or Server 2012.