# How does one make a temporary telnet responder with PowerShell?

Tags: networking, powershell, telnet

I'm looking into making a temporary Telnet server so I can remotely test network connectivity and data transmission integrity.  I don't have the authority to install the telnet server Windows Feature.

Comment: what's the purpose of this? which command are you planning to enter?

Comment: Why not use `winrs` or `New-PSSession` instead?

Answer (score 8):

Don't make a telnet server.

Install OpenSSH and you'll have a secure version of telnet which you can use to run remote commands - all without having to write a single line of code.

Comment: What ports do I have to forward to use OpenSSH?

Comment: Assuming you use the default: 22.

Comment: I second this and 22 is the port you need for ssh

Comment: ... and if it wasn't clear, Telnet is insecure and isn't recommended for production use by any sane administrator, and hasn't been recommended for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this thread of mine, titled `How can I connect to a Windows server using a Command Line Interface?`](https://serverfault.com/q/429426/118258), which might be helpful in accomplishing what you're really trying to do.

Comment: This is good, and includes various options.  An ssh server is good if you are coming remotely from a Linux machine; but using PSExec or native Windows tools may be best if you are coming remotely from another Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are steps from Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770501%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), to achieve your goal.

Comment: Really should come with a disclaimer not to actually do this, though.

Comment: @HopelessN00b: OP should have think about this, before starting this bad idea. What to lose here? =))

Comment: I've got no problem with telling someone how to shoot their foot off, but as a sysadmin, a big part of the job is at least forewarning the person in question that they're about to blow their foot off.  A lot of them pull the trigger anyway, and when they do, it's not your fault, so long as you warned them in advance.

Comment: Forget about them. Less people, less problems.

Comment: I've enabled it, now what command do I use to start it up? Yes, I know Telnet is risky business as it's not encrypted. It's more of a test than anything.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Links die.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers: from Microsoft site? I doubt it.

Comment: @Radio, Microsoft especially. They periodically move things around, causing untold numbers of dead links.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers: I saw they practice a lot of rewrites when they remove link. Plus they realize - they did bad job by causing dead links. Much better lately. =)