# SQL Server 2014 Setup Fails with Error 5 - Terminal Services Unsupported?

Tags: sql-server, mstsc

I am installing SQL Server 2014 on a hosted virtual machine using remote desktop.  When I run setup command line options display using `.\setup.exe /?` , I get the following error:

```
An error occurred during the SQL Server 2014 Setup operation.
Error result: -2067529723
Result facility code: 1220
Result error code: 5
For more information, review SQL Server 2014 Setup logs in your temp folder.
```

This error is instantaneous and it does not generate setup logs as stated.

I checked the system requirements for SQL Server 2014, and it state what I believe to be the root cause of the issue:

> The installation of SQL Server 2014 fails if you launch the setup
>   through Terminal Services Client. Launching SQL Server Setup through
>   Terminal Services Client is not supported.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

I have tried using powershell remoting with a tested core install command line string and it is returning an error indicating that setup is trying to launch a modal dialog:

```
.\setup /ACTION=INSTALL FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=MAIN
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=portland\administrator /QUIETSIMPLE 
/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS 

Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in
UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. 
Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display 
a notification from a service application.
```

What is the recommended approach to installing the product?  Assuming I do not have physical console access, is there an MS approach that would not depend on Microsoft Terminal Services?

Comment: Next action: I am going to further research unattended install practice in MS sources.

Comment: I am moving forward on this.  The powershell remoting error was generated by the target server´s User Account Control Settings prompting due to the installation of software.  I was able to set this to ´never´ logged in as interactive.  After that the setup command ran.

Comment: I am having the same problem. If you figured out the solution and remember what it was, feel free to share...

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know, first of all, the intent of this restriction: are they no longer targeting/supporting this product for non Hyper-V virtualization contexts?

It's been this way for a while, actually.  The same restriction exists for SQL Server 2012, and the reason is that installing SQL server over a Terminal Services session causes problems and non-deterministic behavior.  (Has nothing to do with not supporting other virtualization platforms, and I have both SQL Server 2012 and 2014 instances stood up in Windows Server OSes on the ESXi hypervisor.)

> I would like to know, first of all, the intent of this restriction: are they no longer targeting/supporting this product for non Hyper-V virtualization contexts?

The recommended approach is to install the product from a console connection.

As you say that's not an option, because of your host, I would first try using the command line to install it, [following the instructions for installing SQL Server 2014 on Server Core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669.aspx).  You should be able to use most of the options for [connecting a remote command line in Windows](https://serverfault.com/q/429426/118258) to install SQL server remotely.

Alternately, there are remote GUI options that don't involve Terminal Services.  You could install a VNC server on this VM, or use something like Webex/GoToMeeting/Teamviewer/etc. to get a remote GUI to the server without utilizing Terminal Services for the session.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. First choice would be web ex but is there a way to join a session without TS connection? Any probability I could create an unattended core scripted install and run it outside of the terminal services login using the AT command scheduler?

Comment: How about using something like TeamViewer or the like?

Comment: @JohnMeyer Unfortunately, I'm not really the one to ask about that... I wouldn't install SQL server via a command scheduler.  One of the first things I do on my servers is enable WinRM and PowerShell remoting, so I'd just open a remote PowerShell session and run the installer through that, TBH.  PSExec involves a little less setup, and should work as well, though, worst case, I'd just temporarily install a VNC server on the box, and uninstall it after I finished installing SQL server.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I went forward with powershell remoting and am getting the following error.  Is there a parameter I can use in powershell to overcome this?  I am using a recommended core install command line setup. .\setup /ACTION=INSTALL FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=MAIN /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=portland\administrator /QUIETSIMPLE /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation
. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Comment: Moved info into main question.  Thanks for helping me get closer.