# BAT file that prompts for the computer name that will executed on it

Tags: windows-command-prompt

I need to create a .bat script that will be executed on single/multiple machines

I need first to create a bat that prompts for the computer name that the command will be executed on it

I prefer not to use Ps tools

Comment: i have always been using psexec but we will no longer use it so i'm trying to figure out another solution

i was thinking of creating a command that requests importing the computer name and after importing the computer name the batch starts automatically

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/429426/118258

Comment: Hi there
thank you for your support, this helped me a lot thank you but it's not exactly what i'm looking for 
i need a bat file that requests from me to import the destination computer name. and after importing the destination computer name it executes a command or another bat file on it

thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to provide a list of computernames:

```
@ECHO ON

set controlfile=control.txt

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F %%L IN (%controlfile%%) DO (
  SET "line=%%L"
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  ping !line!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

But I tested this and it seems fine.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P computername=Computername:

ping %computername%
```

(Yes, I just pinged them, you'd need to put your own code there.)

Comment: That's the one i have been looking for

Thank you So Much 
much appreciated