# Connecting a AWS Window 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

So I found remote desktop unusable on a AWS Windows 2012 server, I'm unable to connect via remote desktop.

I have the admin credentials, but without remote desktop I found myself unable to logging in and try to fix the configuration. I suppose that remote desktop license is expired. 
When I try to connect with a Mac OS X application "MS remote desktop" the client gives up the connection without any warning or message. 
It just close the window without any message.

Isn't there an alternative way to connect and fix the remote desktop service?
I can not believe there isn't anything like ssh on windows servers.

Please help me to figure out.

Comment: You can get some information using the information on this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Comment: @Tim thanks for your suggestion, but I have already tried it

Comment: `So I found remote desktop unusable on a AWS Windows 2012 server.` - That's not really telling us anything. Why is it unusable? `I found myself unable to logging in and try to fix the configuration` - Fix what, exactly?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I have just updated the question, but may be I have to delete it because I suppose my answer is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/429426/how-can-i-connect-to-a-windows-server-using-a-command-line-interface-cli

Comment: `I suppose that remote desktop license is expired` - Do you have the RDS role installed? If not, then that's not the problem. 2 RDP sessions are allowed for the purposes of administering the server with no RDS CAL's required. Have you tried connecting from a Windows client?